# Possible bug in fullcalendar's eventClick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Here is the code snippet in question:

```
eventClick: function(calEvent) {
                if(user != calEvent.modified_by && calEvent.modified_by != 0){
                     $('.antoconfirm').css("display", "inline-block");
                }
                $('#fc_edit').click();
                $('#title2').val(calEvent.title);

                //-----------Submit button click-------------------
                $(".antosubmit2").on("click", function(e) {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                  calEvent.title = $("#title2").val();
                  calEvent.confirm = 0;
                  calEvent.backgroundColor = '#ddbd39';
                  dbTitle = calEvent.title;

                  //ajax goes here, works fine

                  calendar.fullCalendar('updateEvent', calEvent);
                  $(".antosubmit2").off("click");
                  $('.antoclose2').click();
                });
                //---------------------------------------------------


               //-----------Close button click-------------------
               $(".antoclose2").on("click", function() {
                  console.log(calEvent.title);
                  $(".antoclose2").off("click");
              });
              //---------------------------------------------------
              return false;
           },
```

`$('#fc_edit').click();` calls the modal in which the editing is done. There are two buttons with the classes "antosubmit2" and "antoclose2". You click on an event, the modal comes up, you change the title, click submit, the modal goes away and voila, the title is changed(from "new1" to "new3" in this example):[Test events, title change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsbGD.png)

When ONLY the submit button is used, everything works fine, you can change one event after the other without incident. On the other hand, when you use the close button on one event and try to change the title on another, the first event will be changed:[Test events, title change after close](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkrb5.png)

Now at the "ajax goes here, works fine" part is an ajax POST, that sends the correct data despite what the calendar shows and after a page reload everything is edited the way it should be.

Is this a bug with fullcalendar's event rendering or does my code fail somewhere?

Comment: I think you need to `.off` _both_ your click handlers whenever either of the buttons is used. Otherwise, those handlers will remain and get used again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to run `.off` against *all* your button click handlers whenever any of your buttons is used. At the moment you only remove the handler for the button that was actually clicked. If you don't remove them, those handlers will remain and get used again if the other button is clicked in future. This is exactly the scenario you have run into.

In the case you described, I suspect because when you closed the first event, you didn't remove the "click" handler related to the "submit" button that went with that event. Then, when you changed the title of the second event, it ran the "click" handler for *both* events, because you never removed the first handler. Hence why the title for the first event gets changed when it shouldn't.